# How to save user id and role id in userrole table while registering user in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a **roles** table, **users** table and **users_role** table. I want to store the user_id and roles_id while registering user. The roles should be 1 by when registering the user. How can i achieve this??

**Roles Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Users table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();             
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();           
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**UserRoles Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')- 
        >onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')- 
        >onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
$user = new User();
... insert data
$user->save();
$user->roles()->attach($roles);
```

Refer to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Comment: thanks.. problem solved.. i just learned attach,detach and sync method... thank you..

Comment: @AnandMainali Happy to help :)